# Знаки вопроса вместо русских символов при считывании и записи данных в БД

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

Реализую обработку данных на сервере из java приложения (без сервлетов, "серв" домашний, на винде, на пару-тройку раз), при попытке получить или отправить данные в БД (executeUpdate, executeQuery) примерно вот таким вот образом:

```
stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `completed` (`id`, `hashcode`, `content`, `userid`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('"+ids+"', '"+hach+"', 'norequest', '"+useri+"', '"+tstm+"')");
```

Получаю мешанину из нормальной латиницы и знаков вопроса.

Кодировка таблицы - utf-8.

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, вы уверены, что кодировку портят именно эти команды? Смотрели на запрос до и после них?

Comment: *Кодировка таблицы - utf-8* А соединения? а собственно передаваемых на сервер данных?

Comment: Исходная строка исправная(с кирилицей), перекодировку делать пробовал. А вот как задать кодировку соединения я не знаю... Пробовал отправлять SET CHARSET UTF-8, не помогло.